# How do I prove that if $g'$ and $fg'$ are integrable then $f$ is integrable along $g$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, bounded-variation, riemann-integration

Let $g:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function of bounded variation such that $g'$ is Riemann-integrable.

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function.

> If $fg'$ is Riemann-integrable, then is $f$ Riemann-Stieltjes integrable along $g$?

I have proven that "If $f|g'|$ is Riemann-integrable then $f$ is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable along $g$"

However, I think this does not help the original problem and I'm stuck for hours.

Thank you in advance

EDIT:

Define $g_1(x)=1/2(V_a^x(g) + g(x) )$ and $g_2(x)=1/2(V_a^x (g) - g(x))$, hence $g=g_1 - g_2$.

I have proven that, for a fixed $\epsilon$, there exists a partition $P=\{x_0,...,x_n\}$ of $[a,b]$ such that for every $s_i,t_i\in [x_{i-1},x_i]$ such that $|\sum_{i=1}^n (f(s_i) -f(t_i)) (g(x_i) - g(x_{i-1})) | < \epsilon$.

Note that the value in the absolute value is the "difference of two sums", namely, $\sum (f(s_i) - f(t_i) ) (g_1(x_i)- g_1(x_{i-1}))$ and $\sum (f(s_i) - f(t_i) ) (g_2(x_i)- g_2(x_{i-1}))$.

Hence we get $|(U(P,f,g_1) - L(P,f,g_1) ) - (U(P,f,g_2) - L(P,f,g_2))| < \epsilon$.

The thing we must show to prove the problem is to show that $|U(P,f,g_1)-L(P,f,g_1) | < \epsilon$ and $|U(P,f,g_2) - L(P,f,g_2) | <\epsilon$. Triangle inequality does not help this

Gaps between lower sums and upper sums $g_1$ and $g_2$ possibly delete each other mutually.

Comment: where do you stuck exactly? does it help, if you assume $g$ be monotone increasing first?

Comment: @user251257 Yes, I have proven that case. But how does that help?

Comment: a function is BV iff it is the difference of two monotone (non-strictly) increasing functions (on a compact interval)

Comment: @user251257 I know that, but still how does that help..? I cannot say where I'm stuck **exactly** since I don't get any inequality that likely to hold yet.

Comment: you just need to show that the Riemann sums convergence and finite sums are linear

Comment: For a fixed $\epsilon$, there exists a partition such that $|\sum_{i=1}^n (f(s_i)-f(t_i) ) (g(x_i)-g(x_{i-1})) | < \epsilon$. If $g$ is monotone, then we can remove $|\cdot|$. However, since $g$ is a **difference** of monotonic functions, it cannot be removed simply.

Comment: triangle inequality?

Comment: @user251257 Under the definition " $mesh(P)\mapsto 0$", that would work, but under Darboux sum definition would not work I guess..

Comment: it works both with characterization. it is just linearity and triangle inequality

Comment: @user251257 I edited my post. I explained why I don't think your argument works. Would you please tell me what I am misunderstanding?

Comment: your definition of Riemann integrable not right. you don't just find one partition. the inequality must hold for any sufficiently fine partition. now for the corrected definition, you just take two partitions, one for $g_1$ and one for $g_2$ and find a finer partition which refines both.

Comment: @user251257 would you please write that as an answer? I completely don't get you right now. I cannot take such two partitions. You are assuming what we have to prove. Why is $f$ integrable along $g_1$ and $g_2$?

Comment: Doesn't $f$ have to be bounded for $\int_a^b f\, dg$ to exist?

Comment: @zhw. You are right. I edited it

Comment: @Rubertos okay. I am not sure. Is your statement really correct? Shouldn't $g$ be absolutely continuous?

Comment: @user251257 I don't know and now I believe it is false.. (I formulated the statement) But I can neither find a counterexample nor  prove it. I have proven it for the case $g$ is $C^1$ though.

Comment: @Rubertos: Well for AC integrator it is well known... (this includes $C^1$). However, I never heard of BV + Riemann integrable derivative implies AC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. It is true for the Lebesgue integral. But it is very technical.

Reference: [Giovanni Leoni: A First Course in Sobolev Spaces](http://www.ams.org/bookstore/pspdf/gsm-105-prev.pdf)

1. A differentiable function has the Lusin N property (Corollary 3.14  cf the reference above).
2. A continuous function with bounded variation and Lusin N property is 
   absolutely continuous (Corollary 3.27).
3. For a absolutely continuous integrator, the statement holds. In fact you have $\int f dg = \int fg'$ (in Lebesgue sense!).